# TRANSFORM ERC 20 vs Sell to pancake swap

Tags: pancakeswap, external-api, 0x

I am able to do the `Sell to pancake swap tranx`

[image]

But failed with the API when i do `TRANSFORM E R C20` Tranx

example of failed: https://bscscan.com/tx/0x3c6044eb59df2d0c037187365f8af8452a13eebaba0ad0fd65d1f84656d74cf3

[image]

I am approving the sell token in both case
and using `https://0x.org/docs/api#get-swapv1quote`

Please help me

what is the difference is both tranx and it display with different titles on metamask
Also what is the work around???

Error:

[image]

https://bscscan.com/tx/0x1926dcbbf96dfae1df3bea051388c9d5c1cfc92566e7eab18cea34a59557d53c

Failed transaction link

Tried to swap BUSD TO AVAX

Query string == https://bsc.api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?sellToken=0x55d398326f99059fF775485246999027B3197955&buyToken=0x1ce0c2827e2ef14d5c4f29a091d735a204794041&sellAmount=1000000000000000&slippagePercentage=0.05&feeRecipient=0xF4b7B3cA0b67D47fB2f172085E034b8f83cE451b&buyTokenPercentageFee=1

development link: https://relaxed-murdock-6b216a.netlify.app/trade

U can try the above app for doing the SWAP with AVAX to BUSD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe You need to add Heigher Gas

Like :-

```
sendTransaction.send{
    from: address
    gas: 500000
 }
```